# Blender Shading does not take colors

Tags: texturing, shaders, export, import, color-management

I have the following problem:
When I look at my imported Fbx object in object mode, it shows the colors as I downloaded it. [image]
But now when I look at the Fbx object in shading mode, it has no textures. How do I get the colors to display in shading mode?
[image]

Comment: Maybe try in the Object Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data ? If it doesn't work please share your file

Comment: https://www.transfernow.net/dl/202204095eRnCARp
This is the Link for the download... Clear Custom Split Normals Data doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

The colors we see in *Solid* mode are the colors set in the material *Viewport Display*, not the real colors. If you switch to *Material* or *Rendered* preview, you'll see a black color because the *Principled BSDF* alpha value is 0, so push it up to 1. Also maybe in the *Object Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data* to avoid bad shading problem. At last create at least one light in your scene, otherwise you won't see any color, or change the world background color.

Comment: Is there any way to use the colors from the Viewport display as material? Sorry if I ask stupid questions, but I am quite new to blender.

Comment: It looks like the Base Color of the Principled BSDF nodes is the same as the color in Viewport Display, but you need to put the Alpha value at 1 and also create at least one light in your scene, otherwise it will remain quite dark (or increase the world color value)

Comment: I have done both. But the object is only visible in black and white.

Comment: You need to put the Alpha at 1 for each of your materials, you have 5 materials, if it still doesn't work please share your file again

Comment: It worked... Thanks:)